# Dynamically adding column to the temptable?

Tags: sql-server

In my sqluery, i am trying to add columns dynamically, but it is showing error Like:
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
 this is my proc

```
        declare @curntyear int
           declare @pasyear int
           declare @sql nvarchar(max)
           declare @temp varchar(50)                
            select  @pasyear=YEAR( DATEADD (YEAR,-3,GETDATE ()))
            select @curntyear =YEAR (getdate())
            print @pasyear
            print @curntyear               
             create table #TempTable (years varchar(30))
             insert into #TempTable  select (cargo+port+railway+estate)as 'sum' from operatingincome where YEAR(createddate)=@pasyear                   
           while (@curntyear >=@pasyear )
            begin
               set @pasyear =@pasyear +1
               --select @temp=(cargo+port+railway+estate)as 'sum' from operatingincome where YEAR(createddate)=@pasyear 
               select  @temp= convert(varchar,(cargo+port+railway+estate),106)   from operatingincome where YEAR(createddate)= @pasyear
               set @sql ='alter table #TempTable add '+ CONVERT(varchar,@pasyear,106)+' varchar(50)'        

                  exec sp_executesql @sql 
                   print @sql
                                           set @sql = 'update #TempTable set '+CONVERT(varchar,@pasyear,106) +'='+@temp +' where years='''+CONVERT(varchar,@pasyear,106)+''
                      exec sp_executesql @sql 
               set @temp =''
              end
              select * from #TempTable
```

i am getting error like this :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2009'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2010'.
alter table #TempTable add 2010 varchar(50)
update #TempTable set 2010=9300 where years=2010

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? And then compare it to the type you used for @sql? Or look at MSDN about sp_executesql and what data types are expected?

Comment: ya it should be @sal nvarchar,

Comment: new error = new question

Comment: i mean i updated my question and execute the query but it is showing error

Comment: new error = new question. We've fixed your original error. Don't change or update your question with brand new unrelated issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're calling sp_executesql with a VARCHAR statement, when it needs to be NVARCHAR.

e.g. This will give the error because @SQL needs to be NVARCHAR

Declare your variable `@sql` `varchar to nvarchar`, that will work fine:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
```

**UPdate:**

Change your `sql` setting as below: you need to use `[]` in column name as `[ColumName]`

```
set @sql ='alter table #TempTable add ['+ CONVERT(varchar,@pasyear,106)+'] varchar(50)'

set @sql = 'update #TempTable set ['+CONVERT(varchar,@pasyear,106) +']='+@temp +' where years='''+CONVERT(varchar,@pasyear,106)+''
```

Comment: i mean i updated my question and executed the query but it is showing error.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
```

to be

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
```

You are told this in the error message and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) (my bold)

> [ @statement= ] statement
>
> Is a **Unicode** string that contains a Transact-SQL statement or batch. statement must be either a **Unicode** constant or a **Unicode** variable.

Comment: ya i change my coade please check

Comment: We've answered the original question. Your new error should be a new question.

Comment: Thank you Mr gbn i saw that one, but still i am not executing that code i am getting different error.